# How to use fork() in unix? Why not something of the form fork(pointerToFunctionToRun)?

Tags: multithreading, unix, process, fork

I am having some trouble understanding how to use Unix's `fork()`. I am used to, when in need of parallelization, spawining threads in my application. It's always something of the form

```
CreateNewThread(MyFunctionToRun());

void myFunctionToRun() { ... }
```

Now, when learning about Unix's `fork()`, I was given examples of the form:

```
fork();
printf("%d\n", 123);
```

in which the code after the fork is "split up". I can't understand how fork() can be useful. Why doesn't fork() have a similar syntax to the above CreateNewThread(), where you pass it the address of a function you want to run?

To accomplish something similar to CreateNewThread(), I'd have to be creative and do something like

```
//pseudo code
id = fork();

if (id == 0) { //im the child
    FunctionToRun();
} else { //im the parent
    wait();
}
```

Maybe the problem is that I am so used to spawning threads the .NET way that I can't think clearly about this. What am I missing here? What are the advantages of `fork()` over `CreateNewThread()`?

PS: I know `fork()` will spawn a new **process**, while `CreateNewThread()` will spawn a new **thread**.

Thanks

Comment: Well... that's the advantage.

Comment: What advantage? I can only see complication.

Comment: fork seams to be more useful when you want to execute same function few times, for having different functions use if

Comment: If the idea is to call the same function several times, why not just call several times the same function, instead? Less complication and less overhead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fork()` says "copy the current process state into a new process and start it running from right here." Because the code is then running in two processes, it in fact returns twice: once in the parent process (where it returns the child process's process identifier) and once in the child (where it returns zero).

There are a lot of restrictions on what it is safe to call in the child process after `fork()` (see below). The expectation is that the `fork()` call was part one of spawning a new process running a new executable with its own state. Part two of this process is a call to `execve()` or one of its variants, which specifies the path to an executable to be loaded into the currently running process, the arguments to be provided to that process, and the environment variables to surround that process. (There is nothing to stop you from re-executing the currently running executable and providing a flag that will make it pick up where the parent left off, if that's what you really want.)

The UNIX `fork()-exec()` dance is roughly the equivalent of the Windows `CreateProcess()`. A newer function is even more like it: `posix_spawn()`.

As a practical example of using `fork()`, consider a shell, such as `bash`. `fork()` is used all the time by a command shell. When you tell the shell to run a program (such as `echo "hello world"`), it forks itself and then execs that program. A pipeline is a collection of forked processes with `stdout` and `stdin` rigged up appropriately by the parent in between `fork()` and `exec()`.

If you want to create a new thread, you should use the Posix threads library. You create a new Posix thread (pthread) using `pthread_create()`. Your `CreateNewThread()` example would look like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>

/* Pthread functions are expected to accept and return void *. */ 
void *MyFunctionToRun(void *dummy __unused);

pthread_t thread;
int error = pthread_create(&thread,
        NULL/*use default thread attributes*/,
        MyFunctionToRun,
        (void *)NULL/*argument*/);
```

Before threads were available, `fork()` was the closest thing UNIX provided to multithreading. Now that threads are available, usage of `fork()` is almost entirely limited to spawning a new process to execute a different executable.

below: The restrictions are because `fork()` predates multithreading, so only the thread that calls `fork()` continues to execute in the child process. Per [POSIX](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html):

> A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), the new process shall contain a replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called. [THR] [Option Start]  Fork handlers may be established by means of the pthread_atfork() function in order to maintain application invariants across fork() calls. [Option End]
>
> When the application calls fork() from a signal handler and any of the fork handlers registered by pthread_atfork() calls a function that is not asynch-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined.

Because any library function you call could have spawned a thread on your behalf, the paranoid assumption is that you are always limited to executing async-signal-safe operations in the child process between calling `fork()` and `exec()`.

Answer (score 7):

History aside, there are some fundamental differences with respect to ownership of resource and life time between processes and threads.

When you fork, the new process occupies a completely separate memory space.  That's a very important distinction from creating a new thread.  In multi-threaded applications you have to consider how you access and manipulate shared resources.  Processed that have been forked have to explicitly share resources using inter-process means such as shared memory, pipes, remote procedure calls, semaphores, etc.

Another difference is that fork()'ed children can outlive their parent, where as all threads die when the process terminates.

In a client-server architecture where very, very long uptime is expected, using fork() rather than creating threads could be a valid strategy to combat memory leaks.  Rather than worrying about cleaning up memory leaks in your threads, you just fork off a new child process to process each client request, then kill the child when it's done.  The only source of memory leaks would then be the parent process that dispatches events.

An analogy: You can think of spawning threads as opening tabs inside a single browser window, while forking is like opening separate browser windows.

Comment: "think of spawning threads as opening tabs inside a single browser window, while forking is like opening separate browser windows" - didn't hear about Chrome? ;-) +1 for a solid point re children able to outlive parents.

Comment: About the resource cleanup by letting the process die: You don't need it per every client request, I remember Apache 1.3 had a parameter that was the number of requests each process handled before dying.

Answer (score 6):

It would be more valid to ask why `CreateNewThread` doesn't just return a thread id like [`fork()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) does... after all `fork()` set a precedent.  Your opinion's just coloured by you having seen one before the other.  Take a step back and consider that `fork()` duplicates the process and continues execution... what better place than at the next instruction?  Why complicate things by adding a function call into the bargain (and then one what only takes `void*`)?

Your comment to Mike says *"I can't understand is in which contexts you'd want to use it."*.  Basically, you use it when you want to:

- run another process using the exec family of functions
- do some parallel processing independently (in terms of memory usage, signal handling, resources, security, robustness), for example:

  - each process may have intrusive limits of the number of file descriptors they can manage, or on a 32-bit system - the amount of memory: a second process can share the work while getting its own resources
  - web browsers tend to fork distinct processes because they can do some initialisation then call operating system functions to permanently reduce their privileges (e.g. change to a less-trusted user id, change the "root" directory under which they can access files, or make some memory pages read-only); most OSes don't allow the same extent of fine-grained permission-setting on a per-thread basis; another benefit is if a child process seg-faults or similar the parent process can handle that and continue, whereas similar faults in multi-threaded code raise questions about whether memory has been corrupted - or locks have been held - by the crashing thread such that remaining threads are compromised

BTW / using UNIX/Linux doesn't mean you have to give up threads for `fork()`ing processes... you can use [`pthread_create()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_create) and related functions if you're more comfortable with the threading paradigm.

Comment: My point is that it is very clear the reason why I am calling CreateThread. I am calling it because I want to run a function in parallel. What are the regular uses of a call to fork?

Comment: @devoured elysium To run a new process (e.g. run a new/different program). fork() is the only way to create a new process in *nix. You'd also do it if you're doing parallell processing where the different "threads" are totally independant of eachother - that way a problem/bug/crash in one of the processes doesn't affect the others, whereas with regular thread, a crash in one of them affects all the others.

Comment: @devoured elysium: of course not: camel_case is abhorrent to Unix.

Comment: @devoured elysium, not really. It provides exec(programPath..) and similar, but that doesn't create a new process, it replaces the existing process with the image of the programPath. CreateProcess() in win32 creates a new process and loads the program image. In *nix you do that in 2 steps, fork() to create a new process, exec() to load the program.

Comment: @devoured elysum: re runProgram(path) - rather, fork() is followed by one of the exec family of functions - the latter kind of overwrites the process calling it with the requested image & restarts execution.  Things like popen() would use fork and exec inside.

Comment: @devoured elysum: re "What are the regular uses of a call to fork?" - to create a second copy of the process, either to exec a different process OR to work cooperatively with the first, perhaps taking over the control/management of certain I/O streams (e.g. TCP clients), or running some time-consuming processing and coordinating results via e.g. shared memory.  Do remember that threads were designed to make it easier/faster to do processing that shares data with the original thread, so fork()ing a process really can seem kind of backwards in certain comparisons.

Comment: Ah. I guess I can understand now its use. It's just that I'm too tied to win32.

Answer (score 2):

Letting the difference between spawning a process and a thread set aside for a second: Basically, fork() is a more fundamental primitive. While SpawnNewThread has to do some background work to get the program counter in the right spot, fork does no such work, it just copies (or virtually copies) your program memory and continues the counter.

Comment: I understand what fork does, what I can't understand is in which contexts you'd want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Fork has been with us for a very, very, long time. Fork was thought of before the idea of 'start a thread running a particular function' was a glimmer in anyone's eye.

People don't use `fork` because it's 'better,' we use it because it is the one and only unprivileged user-mode process creation function that works across all variations of Linux. If you want to create *a process*, you have to call `fork`. And, for some purposes, a process is what you need, not a thread.

You might consider researching the early papers on the subject.

Comment: So, maybe what I don't get is why I'd want to craete a new process. My windows-used brain would think that the only interest in creating a process would be to run another executable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try implementing a shell or launching a daemon any other way.

Comment: What does this Leenooks thing have to with a standard Unix *fork*  (2), anyway?⁠

Answer (score 1):

You `fork` whenever you want to more than one thing at the same time.  It’s called multitasking, and is really useful.

Here for example is a telnetish like program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use IO::Socket;
my ($host, $port, $kidpid, $handle, $line);

unless (@ARGV == 2) { die "usage: $0 host port" }
($host, $port) = @ARGV;

# create a tcp connection to the specified host and port
$handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(Proto     => "tcp",
                                PeerAddr  => $host,
                                PeerPort  => $port)
       or die "can't connect to port $port on $host: $!";

$handle->autoflush(1);              # so output gets there right away
print STDERR "[Connected to $host:$port]\n";

# split the program into two processes, identical twins
die "can't fork: $!" unless defined($kidpid = fork());

if ($kidpid) {                      
    # parent copies the socket to standard output
    while (defined ($line = <$handle>)) {
        print STDOUT $line;
    }
    kill("TERM" => $kidpid);        # send SIGTERM to child
}
else {                              
    # child copies standard input to the socket
    while (defined ($line = <STDIN>)) {
        print $handle $line;
    }
}
exit;
```

See how easy that is?

Comment: Telling someone who is *used* to using threads for concurrency that forking gives you concurrency isn't a big win.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that multi-*processing* not exactly the same as multi-*threading*. The new process created by fork share very little context with the old one, which is quite different from the case for threads.

So, lets look at the unixy *thread* system: `pthread_create` has semantics similar to `CreateNewThread`.

Or, to turn it around, lets look at the windows (or java or other system that makes its living with threads) way of spawning a process identical to the one you're currently running (which is what `fork` does on unix)...well, we could except that there isn't one: that just not part of the all-threads-all-the-time model. (Which is not a bad thing, mind you, just different).

Answer (score 0):

Fork()'s most popular use is as a way to clone a server for each new client that connect()s (because the new process inherits all file descriptors in whatever state they exist).
But I've also used it to initiate a new (locally running) service on-demand from a client.
That scheme is best done with two calls to fork() - one stays in the parent session until the server is up and running and able to connect, the other (I fork it off from the child) becomes the server and departs the parent's session so it can no longer be reached by (say) SIGQUIT.