# Execute functions in the new process

Tags: c, linux

How can I start a new process in C? I tried with `fork()`, but I wish to call some functions in the new process. I have done some googling but couldn't find proper information on what's better: `fork()`, `vfork()`, `exec()` or `clone()`. If you permit another quick question, how can I start new thread?

Comment: I don't understand the question. `fork` is making a clone of the current process, and you can obviously call whatever functions you want after ̀`fork`. And to create threads, learn more about pthreads (the posix thread library) and notably the `pthread_create` function. You really should read a good book on Unix programming!

Comment: Can you please give me any example fork() with function calling?

Comment: Almost all the C code using `fork` is calling some function after that. So I don't understand the question. Please show us what you did code up to now!

Comment: You are aware that fork and exec do different things, right? Fork clones your existing process, while exec family calls replace it with a new one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use fork() in unix? Why not something of the form fork(pointerToFunctionToRun)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160935/how-to-use-fork-in-unix-why-not-something-of-the-form-forkpointertofunctiont)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29#Example_in_C) on Wikipedia; basically, after you fork you have to check the pid to understand if you are in the parent or child process.

```
if (pid == 0) { // child process
    call_child_function();
} else { //parent process
    call_parent_function();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , but how can i call function to new process?

Comment: @Nimit: please, read the provided link, or at least the fork() documentation. He already answered that: check the pid returned and you'll know if you're in the parent or the child process. Then using a `if` condition should suffice to  call whatever functions you might want in each case.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling a function to new process" ??? It does not make much sense for me... (any function your code can reference is callable after the fork in the new process)!!!

Comment: I think he's confused on how the processes interact. One thing that should be clear is that cloning/forking does NOT mean one process can invoke functions in the other process. Each process call its own functions.

Comment: Just to be __very__ clear, I've added a snippet of code.

Answer (score 1):

To start a new child process, you can use my [`popen3()`](http://sites.google.com/site/williamedwardscoder/popen3) function

Comment: I'm not sure it helps the original poster. I believe he don't understand what `fork` does!

Comment: I think my idea was that this tried and tested code would do it for him so he doesn't need to understand it...

Comment: you are right Will. thanks a lot.